# How to compress DEM SRTM files?

Tags: gdal, dem, osgeo4w, srtm

I'm trying to compress my 1.2GB DEM file to reduce its size through the OSGeo4W Shell, but it's not working, as the command only works for RGB images (3 bands), but my DEM only has 1 band (1-band).

I tried the command:

`for %i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES %i %~ni_ok.tif`

Error message:

[image]

edit:
1st message error:

`ERROR6:PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR not supprted on a 1-band raster: only compatible of a 3-band <RGB> raster`

I tried the answer from @bugmenot123:

`for %i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE-co PREDICTOR=2 -co TILED=YES %i %~ni_ok.tif`

but new error message:

```
Usage: gdal_translate [--help-general] [--long-usage]
       [-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/
             CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}] [-strict]
       [-of format] [-b band] [-mask band] [-expand {gray|rgb|rgba}]
       [-outsize xsize[%]|0 ysize[%]|0] [-tr xres yres]
       [-r {nearest,bilinear,cubic,cubicspline,lanczos,average,mode}]
       [-unscale] [-scale[_bn] [src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]]* [-exponent[_bn] exp_val]*
       [-srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize] [-epo] [-eco]
       [-projwin ulx uly lrx lry] [-projwin_srs srs_def]
       [-a_srs srs_def] [-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry] [-a_nodata value]
       [-a_scale value] [-a_offset value]
       [-nogcp] [-gcp pixel line easting northing [elevation]]*
       |-colorinterp{_bn} {red|green|blue|alpha|gray|undefined}]
       |-colorinterp {red|green|blue|alpha|gray|undefined},...]
       [-mo "META-TAG=VALUE"]* [-q] [-sds]
       [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-stats] [-norat]
       [-oo NAME=VALUE]*
       src_dataset dst_dataset
```

Comment: The error message says it. Don't use photometric=ycbcr.

Comment: Please place error messages in the body of the Question as text. Images are not legible on all platforms, and can't be searched by others with the same issue.

Comment: Ok @Vince, i maked update issue

Comment: You are missing a space between `DEFLATE` and `-co`, that was my fault, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most probably do not want to compress DEM data with JPEG, that would be lossy and introduce weird steps in the data.

Instead I recommend the `DEFLATE` compression. To improve the size savings you can also use a predictor for the compressor. See https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html for details and more options.

```
for %i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co TILED=YES %i %~ni_ok.tif
```

If your data is floating point values, use `PREDICTOR=3`.

Comment: This is amazing, I managed to reduce a 1.2GB DEM ALOS PALSAR to just 88MB without loss of pixel information. I will run this DEM on SAG-GIS to compare the results, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't use the lossy JPEG algorithm for compression of DEM data.

Get more info here: https://kokoalberti.com/articles/geotiff-compression-optimization-guide/

You could increase processing speed with GDAL creation options (i.e. NUM_THREADS, GDAL_CACHEMAX)